# RewriteCond if static directory exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite all page requests to .html files
to their .php files
but only if the directory "cms" exists.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /cms -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

I also tried  `<If>` but no success, please help

Need a RewriteCondition NOT based on the REQUEST.

Comment: I would expect you need the absolute path to that "cms" directory, so something like `RewriteCond /var/www/cms -d` ...

Comment: RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}\/cms -d

Comment: Perfect, Thanks !

Comment: _Aside:_ `^(.*)(\.html)$` - The parentheses around `\.html` are serving no purpose here.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}\/cms -d
```

Comment: There's no need to backslash-escape the `/` (slash) here. The slash carries no special meaning in this context, and it's not even a regex.